$user->createToken('laravel')->accessToken; is returns "message": "Invalid key supplied"
In My AWS ec2 ubuntu server the login is working properly it gives user login token.
I have moved the files to serverless aws apllication with same ec2 mysql database credentials.
All other apis are working without authorization.
The login api gives
"message": "Invalid key supplied"
$user->createToken('laravel')->accessToken; is not working .

is your enviroment varibles correctly accessed by your serverless application? if not you need to store it in s3 , parameterstore or secrets manager and access it by your serverless application so that you can run laravel commands.

I dont know what u r saying please explain me. i am new for serverless. what we do in the env file

your app key is not bening able to access by the application, which you usually store it in .env.  how are you accessing the laravel APP_KEY by your serverless application @Brindha

i have added app_key in serverless.yml file. it shows on lambda environment variable list.
